# Would a front-end developer used to Ruby on Rails like working with Magento 2?

Tags: magento, frontend

I am a front-end developer who has worked with Ruby on Rails for 5+ years. Currently considering a job at a company that uses Magento (2). I know little about Magento, but i am getting the feeling by reading about it that it relies heavily on third-party stuff (themes etc). I am a strong believer of separation of concerns (back-end logic decoupled from front-end) and have a healthy aversion against third-party things like frameworks (always hated Bootstrap). Would i be happy working with Magento? Opinions and insight are heavily appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not a stackoverflow-ish question. You could find more useful information elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently considering a job at a company that uses Magento (2). I know little about Magento, but i am getting the feeling by reading about it that it relies heavily on third-party stuff (themes etc).

It's going to depend entirely on the agency you work for and what it is they do.  You'll either hate it, or be mostly OK if mildly annoyed.

Magento's software is built on a web-MVC pattern.  Its routing is based on fixed rules that turn paths into controller class names, or you can inject programatic routing objects yourself.  It has a separate model layer that's similar to ActiveRecord.  It has an EAV Model system built on top of this ActiveRecord-ish system.  It has a view layer that's based on creating layout objects and adding individual template based blocks to this layout object.  There's an XML based DSL for manipulating this layout object.  There is a theme system that lets you distribute custom templates, CSS, and javascript for your system.

Magento's technology is based on PHP, which means you won't have anything like Rack, and you may be deploying to a Apache/MOD_PHP enviornment, or maybe a PHP-FPM enviornment.

Magento 2 is an -- incomplete? -- refactoring of Magento 1, so a lot of programming patterns you'll find will seem incomplete.  Sort of like a house that's structurally sound and wired up, but missing outlets.

What will drive you nuts is the *practice* of Magento Ecommerce development rarely lets you use the underlying framework to develop features.  Instead you rely on a lot of pre-made extensions or themes, and occasionally get to do in-house development on a custom extension.  You will spend a lot of time debugging other people's code.  So find out what the day-to-day work is before you take a job.  Talk to other programmers at the company, and/or ask your potential manager/IT director what the work is.  If it's an agency full of marketing folks and there are no other programmers or IT folks, realize that you're going to be the technology department.

Comment: Thanks! This helps confirm my suspicion that the "building everything from scratch yourself" approach is not really in line with Magento's conventions. I did talk to one of their developers (back-end) and he showed me the codebase which honestly was a big mess. 

Again, thanks for your comment! I really appreciate it!